# How to get a Bandwidth of internet on running video call in vonage API?

Tags: laravel, api, video, vonage, videocall

I have to print a message if bandhwith is down while runing a video call using Vonage API in Laravel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no specific API call to get the bandwidth or display of internet on running video call in vonage API. However, you can use the Get Call Details API to get information about the current call, including the bandwidth used.